# why does minus topPadding not effective when textView has weight?

Tags: android, textview, android-linearlayout, padding

I have this xml:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/account_display_name"
      style="@style/AccountDataDisplayName"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="0dp"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:gravity="center_vertical"/>
  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/account_name"
      style="@style/AccountDataAccountName"
      android:paddingTop="-10dp"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="0dp"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:gravity="center_vertical"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

But I see when I change the paddingTop it doesn't effect the textView position. Why is that and how can i make the second textView higher positioned?

Comment: Try paddingBottom 10dp

Comment: but why does paddingTop not working in my case?

Comment: May be margin top can move this view to above view.. as padding is restricted to it's own view. so it will not be allowed to overlap upper view..

Comment: try using margin to achieve you target needs.

Comment: Try using margins, as they are used for outside spaces. Padding is used for space between border of the view and the actual content and as you set weight on height there might be no more space for padding. So try using margins

Comment: paddingTop -10dp is not supporting in android

Answer (score 0):

1) You are using "center_vertical" which centers the text and the padding starts from there.
2) Negative values are not supported only positive values are.
I think just remove the "center_vertical" and add positive padding.

Comment: what do you mean `Second negative values are not supported `? in linear layout specifically?

Comment: :). I wrote First.... and Second.... (meaning my second point). So to make it clear: negative values are not supported only positive values are